# How did someone else take over my network?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

So I made a network, and someone else became the admin! How did that even happen?

Comment: If you have any images of the situation that may help

Answer (score 1):

If you have been inactive for 30 days someone else will become admin of the network.

This is a change that was introduced in version 1.9.0 of the app:

> Network admin will be transferred after 30 days of inactivity